# Is it possible to configure PostgreSQL to automatically close idle connections?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.3

Clients connect to our PostgreSQL 8.3 database but leave the connections opened. Is it possible to configure PostgreSQL to close those connections after a certain amount of inactivity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I have a solution.
I'll use the tool [PgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) with its parameter `server_idle_timeout`.

---

Another approach would consist in using some cron-like tool running a query periodically to find idle connections.

Once those idle connections are found, a simple call to `pg_terminate_backend` will close them.

See an in depth description of this approach in the anwser of the following question:

[How to close idle connections in PostgreSQL automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30769511/363573)

Answer (score 6):

Since Postgres 9.5 you can configure a timeout for connection in the state "idle in transaction" - which is a bit different just "idle" but typically "idle in transaction" connection generate more problems

See the manual for details: [idle_in_transaction_session_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT)

Comment: Do you know of a parameter for the following states: *idle in transaction (aborted)* or *disabled* ?

Comment: @Stephan: I would assume "idle in transaction (aborted)" is covered by the mentioned option.

Answer (score 2):

Since Postgres 14, you can configure a timeout for idle connections using the `idle_session_timeout` setting:

```
update pg_settings
set setting = 2147483647
where name = 'idle_session_timeout';
```

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-SESSION-TIMEOUT):

> `idle_session_timeout` (`integer`)
>
> Terminate any session that has been idle (that is, waiting for a
> client query), but not within an open transaction, for longer than the
> specified amount of time. If this value is specified without units, it
> is taken as milliseconds. A value of zero (the default) disables the
> timeout.
>
> Unlike the case with an open transaction, an idle session without a
> transaction imposes no large costs on the server, so there is less
> need to enable this timeout than `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`.
>
> Be wary of enforcing this timeout on connections made through
> connection-pooling software or other middleware, as such a layer may
> not react well to unexpected connection closure. It may be helpful to
> enable this timeout only for interactive sessions, perhaps by applying
> it only to particular users.